# Python group last elements in a list

Tags: python

How do i go about trying to group the last elements together in a list , would i need to use something like a dictionary?

```
name,type,hp,shinystatus,move1name,move1dmg,move2name,move2dmg,move3name,move3dmg
```

im taking data from an excel file which holds random data samples from the titles above.

I have grabbed all the data from the file and placed it into the deck list but i want to try and group the moves together within the list.
at the moment my list looks like:

```
import openpyxl
class Deck:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck=[]

    def readFile(self, fileName):
        print("please input the file")
        self.fileName=fileName
        book=openpyxl.load_workbook(self.fileName)
        sheet=book.active
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,values_only=True):
            self.deck.append(row)
    
            print(self.deck)
```

When i run the program it reads the file and stores the values in the deck list. But i want to try and get the output like this below:

```
 [(Damen,Mage,100,True,fireball,63,"Flame",999,"Waterblast",499), .....(MORE cards in  deck list)]
    
    Is it possible to do it like this below? or is this totally incorrect?
    
    [(Damen,Mage,100,True,[(fireball,63),("Flame",999),("Waterblast",499)],(randomName,Astral,150,False,[(Starfall,66)] ..... (More Cards in deck list)]
```

If its easier would it be better to use a dictionary for the moves or soemthing ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: `for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,values_only=True):  

new_row = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4:]]    

self.deck.append(row)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
row = (row[:4], [(row[i], row[i+1]) for i in range(4, len(row)-1, 2)])
self.deck.append(row)
```

If you are going to work exclusively on these fields, I think loading your values to a dictionary would be more neat.